Are there reserved words for Excel Worksheet code names that can't be used?
Are there reserved words in VBA excel that can't be used for naming a codename for a worksheet?
In the Properties window, when I try to use "MasterCampaign" as a codename for a Worksheet with the name of "MasterCampaign" I get the following error message:
"Invalid property value"
All my Worksheet codenames are the same as their name property and Excel allows it.  I can't figure why Excel won't let me use "MasterCampaign" as a Worksheet codename.  This is the only time this has happened.

I don't think it is an invalid sheet name.  https://i.sstatic.net/JfPxWE62.png Please try to create a new workbook and test it.

Did you name anything else "MasterCampaign" in that workbook, like a code module, or a class module for example?

The title of the question should be something like this: Why can't rename worksheet's codename to a specific one?

Tangential, but you can't call a worksheet 'History'.

I am able to recreate this error if I right-click and change the Project Name to "MasterCampaign", then I am no longer allowed to change the worksheet name to "MasterCampaign".


You can't have 2 modules with the same name in an Excel project - and the code name is the module name of the worksheet module.
Reason is that it could create ambigous situations.
If you have a worksheet with the code name Sheet1 and this has a (public) subroutine helloWorld, you can call it from anywhere with Sheet1.helloWorld.
If you have a module MasterCampaign with a routine helloWorld, you can call with MasterCampaign.helloWorld.
However, having a sheet with the same code name as a module (let's say you change the code name of the sheet to MasterCampaign), this would lead to the situation that the compiler no longer knows which routine MasterCampaign.helloWorld is to be called.
Unfortunately the error you face ("Invalid property value") is not very clear. It gets more obvious if you change the order: First set the code name of the sheet and after that change the name of the module to the same name. Now you get an error "Name conflicts with existing module...".


Looking to the answer of kevin: Setting the Project Name and after that the code name of a sheet to the same name indeed leads to the same "Invalid property value" error message. However, you can do it vice versa: When you first set the code name of the sheet and after that change the project name, the VBE doesn't complain. No clue why...

Not the same thing, but worth noting: You should also avoid to give the same name to a module and a routine. It might go well, but it might lead to situation that are ambigious for the compiler and those compiler errors can be hard to identify.
tl;dr: Avoid ambigious names.

Excellent & helpful.

Thanks everyone for your help!  The problem turned out to be that I had previously created a Class Module also with the name of "MasterCampaign."  I changed that to "Master_Campaign" and now I am able to name the Worksheet codename to "MasterCampaign."  I don't use the now-named "Master_Campaign" class and had forgotten it existed.
